# Generic pass events from Leaflet to Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, events, typescript, leaflet

How do I pass events from Leaflet.js into Angular2 in a generic way.

I can create individual `EventEmitter` components on the component and then add specific `.on` subscriptions to these.

e.g. for Marker

```
@Output() click = new EventEmitter();
@Output() dblclick = new EventEmitter();
@Output() mousedown = new EventEmitter();
@Output() mouseover = new EventEmitter();
@Output() mouseout = new EventEmitter();
@Output() contextmenu = new EventEmitter();
```

Followed by

```
this.marker.on({
    'click': event => this.click.emit(event),
    'dblclick': event => this.dblclick.emit(event),
    'mousedown': event => this.mousedown.emit(event),
    'mouseover': event => this.mouseover.emit(event),
    'mouseout': event => this.mouseout.emit(event),
    'contextmenu': event => this.contextmenu.emit(event),
});
```

This allows me to subscribe and pass specific events from Marker to the parent component. BUT this seems very specific and depends on me selecting each specific event type and having a relevant `@Output` to propagate these on.

Is there a more generic way to connect the event system from Leaflet to the event system on Angular2?
I can see that Leaflet has methods to `addEventParent(<Evented> obj)`, but i have not been able to find any examples of this or work out if this is even relevant appropriate for what i am trying to do?